# Setting Permissions in Windows Azure Website

Tags: iis, azure, ftp

Windows Azure has its own set of permissions. How can I change it?

Because I'm using a php website, and I want to delete a file from the folder deployed in my website directory, but I got permission error.

I'm using FileZilla to deploy website files, so I tried to change permissions from FileZilla.

But it doesn't change the permission settings. All the settings are reset automatically.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just edit online?  With either

Visual studio online (skip to step 2)

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//a-quick-look-at-the-new-visual-studio-online-quot-monaco-quot-code-editor

Or the kudu debug console

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/

Comment: Very good answer. I'll try it. :)

Comment: Not a good answer IMHO. First you are adding only links, second none of the links explain how to set/update the permissions in Azure web sites

Comment: The problem is that the question is incorrectly named.  The Links show how to solve the problem (deleting the file). Permissions are set by azure websites and really should not be changed.  If this doesn't solve the problem you have, post a new question and I will answer that one

Comment: I read these site 5 times and couldn't understand how I should make a permission for folder

Comment: This answer is summarized as "don't change permissions .  Use a tool that will edit the file"  if you can make the changes there's no reason to change permissions